# Python - elif statement giving invalid syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I'm having a problem with part of a code I'm writing (as stated in the title).
All the elif are working up to the one on line 10 (i.e. elif inc <= e and inc > d:), which is what is highlighted in IDLE as having an error. Here's the code:

```
def calc(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    if inc <= a and inc >= 0:
        tax = 0.10 * income
    elif inc <= b and inc > a:
        tax = (0.10 * a) + (0.15 * (income - a))
    elif inc <= c and inc > b:
        tax = (0.10 * a) + (0.15 * b) + (0.25 * (income - b))
    elif inc <= d and inc > c:
        tax = (0.10 * a) + (0.15 * b) + (0.25 * c) + (0.28 * (income - c)                                           
    elif inc <= e and inc > d:
        tax = (0.10 * a) + (0.15 * b) + (0.25 * c) + (0.28 * d) + (0.33 * \
            (income - d))
    elif inc <= f and inc > e:
        tax = (0.10 * a) + (0.15 * b) + (0.25 * c) + (0.28 * d) + (0.33 * \
            e) + (0.35 * (income - e))
    elif inc > f:
        tax = (0.10 * a) + (0.15 * b) + (0.25 * c) + (0.28 * d) + (0.33 * \
            e) + (0.35 * f) + (0.396 * (income - f)
    tax_str = str(tax)
```

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238603/elif-statement-in-python-invalid-syntax

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
tax = (0.10 * a) + (0.15 * b) + (0.25 * c) + (0.28 * (income - c)
```

You forgot to add a `)` at the end.

Python then interprets the next line as a continuation of the previous line, hence the SyntaxError.