# elif statement in python invalid syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, cs50

Pretty new with python, but have some experience in C.

Does the if statements work the same way as in C? Putting an if statement below another if statement to check for false return.

There seem to be an issue with me trying to use an elif statement in python can some one help me figure out what is the issue here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# TODO
#import nltk
from helpers import get_user_timeline
from analyzer import Analyzer

#ZYMAYLA'S HINTS

#ensure proper usage
    #argv
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: ./smile @username")

    # absolute paths to lists
    positives = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "positive-words.txt")
    negatives = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "negative-words.txt")

#get tweets
    ##get_user_timeline (in helpers.py)
    if get_user_timeline(screen_name, count=200) is False:
        #Check if successful
        #if private account or does not exist(unsuccessful)
        #error message if unsuccessful(sys.exit)
        sys.exit("account either private or does not exist")
        #tokenize the tweet (like we did in analyzer.py for "smile")

        #tokenizers are part of natural language toolkit
        #use a TweetTokenizer to split into a list of words


    #analyze tweets
    #initialize Analyzer
    analyzer = Analyzer(positives, negatives)
    #instantiate Analyzer, iterate over every token scoring them pos,neg,neutral (this will indicate if the tweet is posistive/negative/neutral)
    score = analyzer.TweetAnalyzer(sys.argv[1])

    if score > 0.0:
        #print score
        print(colored("{}".format(score), "green", end=''))
        #print tweet
        print("{}".format(tweet)

    elif score < 0.0:
        print(colored("{}".format(score), "red", end=''))
        #print tweet
        print("{}".format(tweet)

    else:
        print(colored("{}".format(score), "yellow", end=''))
        #print tweet
        print("{}".format(tweet)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please include the traceback.

Comment: The line before the `elif` is missing a close parenthesis.

Comment: You have mismatched parenthesis in some `print` statement

Comment: Thanks! Included it and have got more issues. haha will be solving that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a parenthesis on the previous line:

```
    print("{}".format(tweet)
```

This should be:

```
    print("{}".format(tweet))
```

... And the same goes for the identical `print`s on lines 48 and 53.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

the last print statement in your if/elif/else blocks are all missing a closing bracket

Comment: Thanks for that!